# Rewrite URL in ASp.net by more then one pera

Tags: asp.net

I want to rewrite the following url

> http://localhost:35716/check/Result.aspx?City=30&Area=3135&School=1&Class=1&Stream=4&RollNo=1&Section=1&Exam=1

like this

> http://localhost:35716/check/Result/City30/Area3135/School1/Class1/Stream4/RollNo1/Section1/Exam1

Answer (score 0):

Get the url to a string by using [`Uri.AbsoluteUri Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri(v=vs.110).aspx).
And then use `replace` function to replace `=` and `.aspx?`.

**Code**

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
url = url.Replace(".aspx?", "").Replace("=", "").Replace("&", "/");
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Comment: But frnd i want This http://localhost:35716/check/Result/City30/Area3135/School1/Class1/Stream4/RollNo1/Section1/Exam1

Comment: You just need to replace the `.aspx?` and `=` right? The above code will do the same.

Comment: from this Code Url is change but how it's set at url

Comment: Yes but i want Url Rewrite

Comment: Dear It's not working what i want This Code Replace the url but it's not a URL REwite

Comment: after replacing the characters in the url, redirect to that.